# VBA for Outlook - Change Subject Line using Right

Tags: vba, outlook

I am trying to change incoming emails subject line to only the last 11 characters of the subject line. When I use `Item.Subject = Right(Item.Subject,11)` it does not work.

Can someone assist?

Full code.

```
Sub ChangeSubjectForward(Item As Outlook.MailItem)
Item.Subject = Right(Item.Subject, 11) 
Item.Save
End Sub
```

Comment: No errors, just does not change the subject.

Comment: Have you tested that the code is actually running?

Comment: You need to test `If Len(Item.Subject) > 11 Then`

Comment: Yes. And if I change it to = "Test" it works fine. Do I need a. value at the end? Does it work like vba for excel?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Updating email subject in Outlook VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39134335/updating-email-subject-in-outlook-vba)

Comment: There is nothing wrong with you code, how are you calling/running the code?

Comment: where does the message come from?

Comment: @0m3r I am calling the code with an Outlook rule "Run a Script".

Comment: @Dmitry Streblechenko The email comes from multiple users, but will always use the same email template.

Comment: Does the code actually run?

Comment: @Dmitry Streblechenko Yes it does - If I change the equals to, to "Test" it will change just fine. But switching it back to `Right(Item.Subject, 11)` does nothing.

Comment: Have you tried to add a line like MsgBox Item.Subject & vbCrLf & Right(Item.Subject, 11)

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko - The msgbox prompted fine, but it still has the original subject line in it.

Comment: But did the second line of the prompt show the expected 11 chars long value?

Comment: @Dmitry Streblechenko I went to test and verfiy, now I cant even get a msgbox to prompt.... I'm lost.

Comment: So that manes your script is not running. Or that execution does not get to that line.

Comment: Delete your rule and re-create it again

Answer (score 0):

I found another SO thread that says you can't modify the subject of a message without opening it first. We can use ActiveInspector to get a handle on the Item after we display it. Then we can change it, save it, and close it. I added a check to see if the subject is actually longer than 11 characters before we attempt to truncate it.

Try this:

```
Public Sub ChangeSubjectForward(ByRef Item As Outlook.MailItem)
    Debug.Print Now                              '  This shows you when the code runs
    If Len(Item.Subject) > 11 Then
        Debug.Print "Subject is too long. Trimming..." '  This shows that we tried to truncate.

        Item.Display                             'Force the pop-up

        Dim thisInspector As Inspector
        Set thisInspector = Application.ActiveInspector

        Set Item = thisInspector.CurrentItem     ' Get the handle from the Inspector
        Item.Subject = Right$(Item.Subject, 11)
        Item.Save
        Item.Close
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I wish I understood all of that. I am decently new to VBA and I have never used it in Outlook. That still does not work. Could it be the way my rule is set up? Could that prevent it?

Comment: Sorry, I added explanations. I also added some debug lines so you can see when your code ran. Just open the "Immediate Window" `CTRL+G` and you will see the debug messages when the code runs.

Comment: Thank you so much. That is awesome info.

Comment: Absolutely not - to change any property, displaying the item is not necessary. As long as you call Save.

Comment: @HackSlash - This is getting closer! The email opens, subject changes, but the window does not close. Also, the Subject in the Reading Pane does not change. For the window now closing, could I add `MailItem.Close` after `Item.Save`?

Comment: I added `Item.Close`. Try that.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a [macro rule](https://www.slipstick.com/outlook/rules/outlooks-rules-and-alerts-run-a-script/) then run the below code:

```
Sub save_to_dir_test1(mymail As MailItem)
Dim strID As String
Dim objMail As Outlook.MailItem

strID = mymail.EntryID
Set objMail = Application.Session.GetItemFromID(strID)
objMail.Subject = Right(m.Subject, 11)
objMail.Save
Set objMail = Nothing
End Sub
```

For more information, please refer to this link:

[Run a Script Rule: Change Subject then Forward Message](https://www.slipstick.com/outlook/rules/run-script-rule-change-subject-message/)

[Getting the incoming email in outlook via VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14020905/getting-the-incoming-email-in-outlook-via-vba)